# Looping through promises

Tags: javascript, forms, promise, formvalidation.io

I am trying to validate 10 form fields using formvalidation.io. If any of the 10 validations fail I need to return false. However to access whether a validation has passed or not you need to call a promise.

```
var otherFacilityFields = [
    "addressLine1",
    "city"
];

  fieldsPass = otherFacilityFields.every(function(field) {
    fv.validateField(field).then(function(status) {
        if (status != 'Valid') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
  });
```

The above doesn't work because promises aren't synchronous.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I guess you meant to say "synchronous" not asynchronous

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to list out all 10 promises. Then it seems like I'd have to loop through the array and check if any were false. Yes, I meant synchronous.

Comment: so you can still loop. Map them to an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your fields to create an array of promises. Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for those promises to resolve and *then* use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the response status of each validation.

I've used [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) here but `Promise.all(promises).then` would work equally well. I've also mocked up a demo validation routine so you can see it in action. Simply change the resolve from 'Valid' to 'Invalid' and rerun the demo to see `allValid` equal `false`.

```js
const fv = {
  validateField() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('Valid'), 1000);
    });
  }
}

const otherFacilityFields = ['addressLine1', 'city'];

// `map` over the fields and return a
// validation promise for each
const promises = otherFacilityFields.map(field => {
  return fv.validateField(field);
});

(async () => {
  try {

    // await the promises to all resolve
    const res = await Promise.all(promises);

    // Use `every` to check the status of each validation
    const allValid = res.every(status => status === 'Valid');
    console.log(allValid);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using javascript has async and await you could do something like

```html
fieldsPass = otherFacilityFields.every(async function(field) {
    let status = await fv.validateField(field)
    if (status != 'Valid') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
```

or you can try some solution using Promise.all() 
or you can use global variable like

```html
  let valid = true
  let length = otherFacilityFields.length
  fieldsPass = otherFacilityFields.every(function(field) {
    fv.validateField(field).then(function(status) {
        if (status != 'Valid') {
            valid = false;
        }
        valid = true;
        length = length - 1
        if(length == 0)
          //return the valid value
    });
  });
```

Comment: global? How would that help? You still need to know when all of them are done. Every is not going to get the true/false

Comment: Still not going to work because of being asynchronous. Maybe if it was forEach.... and you still can not return

Comment: I meant to use foreach, somehow i thought you were doing foreach. so why not using foreach?

Comment: (I am not the OP)